# Power BI: need a formula to create a column from subtracting two distinct dates

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a date for when someone last bought something (lastbuy) and have an end date (lastday) column and I want to create a new column with this new value which will be a whole number. FYI, lastday and lastbuy are both Date/Time data types. I tried the following:

```
Column_name = DATEDIFF(lastday, lastbuy, day)
_______________________________________________

Column_name = COUNTX('Table_name', [lastday] - [lastbuy])
```

Comment: The second one doesn't make sense, but why doesn't the first work?

Comment: The first one works but the problem is that it is returning a value of zero each time I refresh it, is it possible that there might be a missing connection in the data model?